# How to upload a new version of a task group via api?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to write some software to programmatically manage a set of TaskGroups across multiple projects. My issue is that if I have a TaskGroup with multiple published versions, I can't seem to get that update into a different project.

If I try to to just `POST` the updated version of the TaskGroup, I get a

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.MetaTaskDefinitionExistsException

because it detects that it has the same name as another TaskGroup.

If, however, I try to `PUT` the update into the existing TaskGroup, it for some reason acts like it can't find the TaskGroup with that ID (even though I have verified that it exists in that project).

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a task group in a project, you should follow [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to update it:

`PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskGroupId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

If you want to use the task group in other projects, you can try to [list the task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and then [create a task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) in new project:

List task group:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskGroupId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

Add a task group:

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this is exactly what I am trying and exactly what is not working. 

I have found some more info. It appears that I first have to publish a draft version and then publish it as a preview and then publish that preview. The API doesn't mention this at all so I am doing a fair bit of trial and error to get it working.